# Python GUI connection to SQL Server database

Tags: python, sql-server, user-interface, stored-procedures, crud

I'm developing a GUI in Python in Visual Studio Code, which is connected to SQL Server 2019 database. I created a number of tables in the database, taking normalization into consideration.

I'm not quite sure which approach I should take, I need to perform CRUD operation on multiple tables tables simultaneously from the GUI. Would using stored procedures be the best option, and will i have to create the stored procedure in SQL Server 2019 and then call the procedure name in VSC? Is there a more effective way to achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: Are you planning to use this application with single client only? Won't this database in future be located on server to work with multiple GUI instances? If single client only, than stored procedures may be good choice. If not - I'd better suggest doing more work on client (in GUI) to reduce server load.

Comment: Currently its for a single client user, but now that you mentioned the reality of the database being possibly  on the server  this got me thinking. Thanks for your advice